# Make .text section execute-only

Tags: linker-scripts

I have been trying to make my .text section execute-only for some time, however the linker insists on merging rodata with it and makes it RE. Imagine a simple linker script where I need 3 loadable segments, .text E, .rodata R, .data RW.

How can I achieve this?

As a backup solution I can post-process the ELF binary, however I still need 3 loadable segments for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, with some work, to make this happen. So, the first thing you need to do is to separate the .text and .rodata segments, which I was *only* able to do by creating MEMORY areas manually, and then using them for each part of the code. GCC will never emit data into the code segments (and if it does, it's a bug). Here's an example 64-bit RISC-V linker script:

https://gist.github.com/fwsGonzo/993e0ea121ad12db69913fc870a68736

However, the linker will refuse to remove the read-bit from the executable segment. To combat that we need to post-process the binary using chperm:

https://gist.github.com/fwsGonzo/e3dbcd9097953e7e113fd3f3ada04316

Simply call it like this:

```
chperm <file> 0 x
```

In CMake you would post-process it like this:

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CHPERM} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${NAME} 0 x
)
```

I wrote some words when I was implementing this feature for myself:
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/issues/668

Comment: FYI: https://gist.github.com/fwsGonzo/9184d9352ef37bce0ad03e4cef0c0f13 leads to 404.

Comment: I uploaded another linker script